# Variable precision in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sqldatatypes

I have a column which consists of three different types of numbers:

- **Type 1** has no digits after decimal point like `5`, `17`, etc.
- **Type 2** has one digit after decimal point like `27.5`, `11.8`, etc.
- **Type 3** has 2 digits after decimal points like `227.64`, `35.77`, etc.

I want the **Type 1** numbers to have a 0 after decimal point so that they become `22.0`, `11.0` and so on while the **Type 2** and **Type 3** numbers remain unaffected.

Comment: The place to do this is in your presentation layer where you would convert the value to a string in your desired format. (because 22.0 *is* 22 and the latter is what is stored)

Comment: Use application layer to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by pushing value into a string.

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE (myValue FLOAT)

INSERT  INTO @table
        (myValue)
VALUES  (5),
        (17),
        (27.5),
        (11.8),
        (227.64),
        (35.77)

SELECT  CASE WHEN CAST(myValue AS VARCHAR(20)) LIKE '%.%' THEN CAST(myValue AS VARCHAR(20))
             ELSE CAST(myValue AS VARCHAR(20)) + '.0'
        END
FROM    @table
```

This is a poor solution at best.  Your better maintaining your data in its original format and then handling your formatting in the presentation layer as already stated by Ankit. I know its not always possible, but the data place is not really the place to do this.

Comment: Must state this is a Microsoft SQL Server answer - rather than plsql / oracle. Hopefully it will lead you in the right direction though.

Answer (score -1):

What is the data type of the column?

Try:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN LEN(RIGHT([MyColumn], CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([MyColumn])))) >= 3
    THEN [MyColumn]
ELSE CAST(CAST([MyColumn] AS NUMERIC(8,1)) AS NVARCHAR(10))
END AS [MyColumn]

FROM [MyTable]
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an Oracle-based solution, which is what the OP is after (see the tags).